# Get more than 100 data from Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I use this function when I get user page likes from Facebook Graph API. Before 2 months ago this function is working and get  more than 100 data from Facebook. but now this function get only lower than 100 page likes for every user . Facebook API has a next section and normally this function is working good. How can I resolve this problem? Facebook API example below the code. I need to go next page of the api but I can't.

```
    public function handle() {
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'xxxxxx',
        'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
    ]);

    //$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($this->accessToken);

    $likes = $fb->get("/$this->uid/likes?fields=id,name,fan_count,category,picture&limit=100000", $this->accessToken)->getGraphEdge();
    $totalLikes = array();
    if ($fb->next($likes)) {
        $likesArray = $likes->asArray();
        $totalLikes = array_merge($totalLikes, $likesArray);
        while ($likes = $fb->next($likes)) {
            $likesArray = $likes->asArray();
            $totalLikes = array_merge($totalLikes, $likesArray);
        }
    } else {
        $likesArray = $likes->asArray();
        $totalLikes = array_merge($totalLikes, $likesArray);
    }

    if (Likes::where('facebook_id', '=', $this->uid)->exists()) {
        //Session::put('facebookId', $uid);
    } else {
        foreach ($totalLikes as $totalLike) {
            $pageLike = Likes::create();
            $pageLike->facebook_id = $this->uid;
            $pageLike->page_id = $totalLike['id'];
            $pageLike->page_name = $totalLike['name'];
            $pageLike->fan_count = $totalLike['fan_count'];
            $pageLike->category = $totalLike['category'];
            $pageLike->save();
        }
        //Session::put('facebookId', $uid);
    }

} //function end -- //
```

---

```
   {
"data": [
],
"paging": {
"cursors": {
"before": "MTUzNTIwNjI0NzQ5MzEy",
"after": "MzQ0NTkzNzU3Mjk5"
},
"next": ""
}
}
```

Comment: Any good API would restrict the number of records returned in a single request. You’ll need to traverse the pages of results as per Facebook’s documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging

Comment: but this code was working two months ago. I think next function is not working but why?

Comment: reduce the limit to something like 100. that is WAY too high right now. and use paging, as martin bean suggested.

Comment: @tom it depends on an external API that could change at any moment depending on the release model of that API. We also don't know if you're keeping the API version locked or if it's taking whatever is newly released. Not saying that's the issue but I'd check that out too, make sure it's what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the solution with PHP so I maked a Python code for that. Here is the code below. if someone else needs it. 
You have to send two parameters from terminal for this function. This is the terminal code below: python get_like_info.py "facebook_id" "access_token"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import urllib2
import MySQLdb
import sys
import time
import datetime

uid = sys.argv[1]
access_token = sys.argv[2]
def main(uid = uid, access_token = access_token):
    db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'databasename', charset='utf8')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    picture = ""


    fb_data = get_link("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{0}/likes?fields=id%2Cname%2Cfan_count%2Ccategory%2Cpicture&access_token={1}&limit=100".format(uid, access_token))
    i = 0

    query = "SELECT DISTINCT facebook_id FROM likes WHERE facebook_id = {0}".format(uid)
    a = cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
    for key in fb_data["data"]:
        i += 1
        #print (str(i) + " " + key["name"]).encode('utf-8') 
        picture = ""
        if not rows:
            cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO `likes` (facebook_id, page_name, page_id, fan_count, category, picture,created_at,updated_at) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', (uid, key["name"], key["id"], key["fan_count"], key["category"], picture, time2, time2))
            db.commit()
    try:
        while fb_data["paging"]["next"]:
            #print fb_data["paging"]["next"]
            fb_data = get_link("{0}".format(fb_data["paging"]["next"]))
            for key in fb_data["data"]:
                i += 1
                #print (str(i) + " " + key["name"]).encode('utf-8')
                if not rows:
                    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO `likes` (facebook_id, page_name, page_id, fan_count, category, picture,created_at,updated_at) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', (uid, key["name"], key["id"], key["fan_count"], key["category"], picture, time2, time2))
                    db.commit()
    except KeyError:
        print ("key error")
        sys.exit()



def get_link(link):
        fb_link = urllib2.urlopen(link)
        fb_json = fb_link.read()
        fb_data = json.loads(fb_json)
        return fb_data



main()
```